# Get pixel colors in medium trust asp net: only getpixel()?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I'd like to get pixel colors of bitmap; I know that `Lockbits` method and pointers are very fast to obtain this but I'm using a medium trust web server which doesn't let use pointers and `Marshal.Copy` too.
In this case Is only  possible to use `Getpixel` method or there are others?